# Handling focus on a toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to keep the focus on the toggle button after it gets pressed.
Right now, when I click on the button, the focus jumps to the top of the page. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
  <button ng-if=“test” ng-click=“deactivate()">Deactivate</button>
  <button  ng-if=“!test” ng-click="activate()”>Activate </button>
```

JS

```
 $scope.activate = function () {
          var activateButton = document.activeElement;
            if ($scope.some.length) {
                $scope.enableSome($scope.some, true);
            }
            activateButton.onclick = function () {
              activateButton.focus();
            };
        };

 $scope.deactivate = function () {
          var activateButton = document.activeElement;
            if ($scope.some.length) {
                $scope.enableSome($scope.some, false);
            }
          activateButton.onclick = function () {
            activateButton.focus();
          };
        };
```

Comment: Does `enableSome()` change the value of `test`?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, if the user click on the Activate button it changes the text to Deactivate and vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two buttons that are added/removed from the DOM based on the `ng-if` condition ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)).

Your button is not getting focused because the activate button is getting removed while the deactivate button is added, and vice versa.

We can refactor the two buttons into one using a `toggleActivation()` method.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = false;
  $scope.some = [1, 2, 3];

  $scope.enableSome = function(some, activate) {
    //Do whatever
    console.log('enableSome called with activate = ' + activate);
  }

  $scope.toggleActivation = function() {

    //Toggle the state
    $scope.test = !$scope.test;
    
    if ($scope.some.length) {
      $scope.enableSome($scope.some, $scope.test);
    }
    
    //The button is still focused!
    console.log('Focused element: ', document.activeElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="toggleActivation()">
    {{test ? "Deactivate" : "Activate"}}
  </button>
</div>
```